# Permissions of shared folder with VirtualBox: Host Windows 7 and Guest Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, mount, virtualbox, fstab, chmod

Using Virtualbox `Version 5.1.26  r117224` on Host Windows 7  and Guest Ubuntu 16.04 I'm stuck trying to share host folder.  I already installed Virtualbox guest additions and performed a restart.

For example I want to share the directory Downloads.

My fstab:

```
Downloads                 /mnt/host/sf_Downloads vboxsf  uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

`ls -la` gives,

```
dr-xr-xr-x  1 bob bob    8192 sept. 11 10:01 Downloads
```

`id` gives,

```
uid=1000(bob) gid=1000(bob) groups=1000(bob),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),999(vboxsf)
```

How can I change the permission of the folder to `drwxrwxr-x`?

Comment: Please which is the host here, windows or ubuntu, I suspect Ubuntu is guest in any case do you have the Virtualbox guest additions installed and did you restart Ubuntu guest after adding the share folder?

Comment: Yes you are right. Host: windows 7 and Guest: Ubuntu 16.04. Yes I installed Virtualbox guest additions. Yes I restarted several time trying various things. Thanks